# Creating a header that has one fluid side

Tags: html, css

please see the attached wireframe. I'm using blueprint css. I want the every thing except the header to be in a 980px container.

For the header, I would like the left column to be fluid. Always growing to touch the left of the browser. How can you build a container, that has a header that is fluid on only one side?

I hope the wireframe helps explain the problem. If not please let me know. Thanks

[image: Wireframe]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I have interpreted your question correctly, but I think the only way to do this is playing around with the z-index of the container and banner area.

For example, your CSS would be:

```
body { margin: 0; }
#container { width:980px; margin: 0 auto; z-index: 1; background-color: black; height:500px; }
#logo { width:200px; height:50px; background-color: red; }
#header-left { position: absolute; top:0; left:0; height:50px; width:50%; z-index: 0; background-color: red; }
```

Then for your HTML:

```
<div id="header-left"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="logo"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I'm right, you want your header always to be on the top and left corner right and not affect containers position? Well why don't you just take that header out of your container, make sure your body margins are set at 0 so you header actually is completely at the top and left corner of the document and make your header have absolute position.

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

.header {
    width: 200px;
    position:absolute;
}
.container {
    width: 980px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

<body>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry that's not it. In the container (980px) I want a header that's 200px wider, positioned to the left of the container. Then outside the container, in the body I want a div to strech from the browser's left edge, all the way to the header (200px unit) but not past that. I don't want the fluid header bkg to to all the way to the right brower side. Does that help?